# Maxscript: how do I change the value of a key?

Tags: animation, maxscript

I have an object which is pathconstrained.
It has two keys, one at frame 0 and one at frame 100.

I want to change the value of the second key.

I can access it with:
$.pos.controller.Path_Constraint.percent.keys[2]

But I'm not able to SET IT to a different value.

How do I change its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting its `.value` to a different one should definitely work.